# Is there a variable in which the console output is stored? (Codeception)

Tags: php, codeception

Is there a variable in which the console output is stored?
If I have this variable I can save it in a file and open it later.

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge.

The [`codecept_debug()`](https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Functions#codecept_debugdata) function exists for this reason: Codeception basically takes over stdout, and only data sent through this function will appear in your test output.

The best I could suggest would be to have your test process send everything it outputs to a file for you to consult later. If you go that route, you'll probably want to disable the `colors` setting in your Codeception configuration (see [related documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Configuration#Global-Configuration)).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.